# Looping through array of object based on a key and change its value in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, mongoose, aggregate

Loop through a object array find a key and then change its value in javascript

Hi I have a below array of objects

```
[
  {
    createdDateTime: {
      '$gte': '2023-02-08T00:00:00.000Z',
      '$lte': '2023-05-09T23:59:59.000Z'
    }
  },
  { user: 'customer' }
]
```

I want to change it to below

```
[
  {
    createdDateTime: {
      '$gte':new Date( '2023-02-08T00:00:00.000Z'),
      '$lte':new Date( '2023-05-09T23:59:59.000Z')
    }
  },
  { user: 'customer' }
]
```

What I tried

```
var check = filtersFromRequest.some(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty("createdDateTime"));
  if(check){
   // stuck here as what to do , 
  }
```

Kindly guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the array, and then for each object, check if it has the `createdDateTime` property. If it does, update the `$gte` and `$lte` values with new Date objects.

Here's how you can do it:

```
// Assuming payloads is your initial array
const updatedPayloads = payloads.map(obj => {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty('createdDateTime')) {
    let newObject = {...obj}; // clone the object to avoid modifying original
    if(newObject.createdDateTime.hasOwnProperty('$gte')) {
      newObject.createdDateTime['$gte'] = new Date(newObject.createdDateTime['$gte']);
    }
    if(newObject.createdDateTime.hasOwnProperty('$lte')) {
      newObject.createdDateTime['$lte'] = new Date(newObject.createdDateTime['$lte']);
    }
    return newObject;
  } else {
    return obj; // return object as it is if it does not contain 'createdDateTime'
  }
});
```

This code will create a new array called `updatedPayloads` with the date strings replaced by Date objects. The original `payloads` array will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways. One is:

```
const firstObject = [
  {
    createdDateTime: {
      '$gte': '2023-02-08T00:00:00.000Z',
      '$lte': '2023-05-09T23:59:59.000Z'
    }
  },
  { user: 'customer' }
];

const secondObject = firstObject.map(obj => {
  if (obj.createdDateTime) {
    obj.createdDateTime['$gte'] = new Date(obj.createdDateTime['$gte']);
    obj.createdDateTime['$lte'] = new Date(obj.createdDateTime['$lte']);
  }

  return obj;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.forEach()

```
filtersFromRequest.forEach( item =>{
    const createdDateTime = item.createDateTime;
    if( createdDateTime ){
        createdDateTime.$gte = new Date(createdDateTime.$gte);
        createdDateTime.$lte = new Date(createdDateTime.$lte);
    }
});
```